# Question about JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

If I console.log(result); I get

```
{"MSG":"WRONG","QUESTIONID":182.0}
```

But If I console.log(result.QUESTIONID); I get

```
undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: works fine to me... http://jsfiddle.net/yG8Pd/ are you sure, that's all of your json?

Comment: That should work. Some more code will be useful here if it's not working for you.

Comment: How is the json being prepared? What happens when you do `$.parseJSON(result).QUESTIONID` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to do this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    type: "POST"
    ,dataType: 'json'
    ,error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('#msg').text(textStatus).addClass('err');
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't *need* `$.ajaxSetup()`, but you can optionally use it. This sets defaults for *all* your ajax requests.

Comment: passing 'json' as the last argument in a query call would be quite enough.